# getUserMedia in IE 11 or MediaStream in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, temasys

I am trying to use `getUserMedia` function with the help of [temasys](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TWPP/pages/4849909/How+to+integrate+the+Temasys+WebRTC+Plugin+into+your+website) plugin in IE 11. `getUserMedia` returns an instance of MediaStream which is not supported by IE.

Here is my sample code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toggle: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AdapterJS.webRTCReady(isUsingPlugin => {
      console.log('isUsingPlugin....', isUsingPlugin)
      navigator.getUserMedia({
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            maxWidth: 640,
          },
          optional: [
            { maxFrameRate: 120 },
            { minFrameRate: 120 },
          ],
        },
      }, (st) => {
        try {
          this.videoRef.srcObject = st
        }
        catch (eee) {
          console.error(eee)
        }
        this.setState({ toggle: !this.state.toggle })
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('error....', error)
      })
    })
  }
  setRef = ref => {
    this.videoRef = ref
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <video ref={this.setRef} autoPlay={true} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

st is an instance of MediaStream which is not supported by IE. The issue is on the line:

```
this.videoRef.srcObject = st
```

I have also tried

```
this.videoRef.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(st)
```

which is also not working in IE.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/97059/).

How will I get it work on IE? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are using a WebRTC adapter, which helps standardising the API for performing these tasks.

Temasys has their own adapter that builds on top of WebRTC adapter and add supports to their plugin while keeping the similar interface.

So, MediaStream and other things will also be supported on IE as it is defined by that adapter library.

WebRTC AdapterJS: https://github.com/webrtc/adapter

Temasys AdapterJS: https://github.com/Temasys/AdapterJS

I hope this solves your issue.

Check this sample code for implementation: https://github.com/Temasys/Google-WebRTC-Samples/blob/master/src/content/getusermedia/canvas-video/js/main.js

Comment: I have already integrated [Temasys AdapterJS](https://github.com/Temasys/AdapterJS). But still, it is not working.

Comment: Can you include the error/stacktrace that you are getting here?

Comment: There is no error when I am using `this.videoRef.srcObject = st` and it is not showing anything.

Comment: I hope you are following the docs properly. I do not see you attachMediaStream to your video element. Because IE's video element can't take the MediaStream object, temasys converts it into an object element and does some stuff with it.

myVideoElement = attachMediaStream(myVideoElement, myStream);

as given in the docs: https://confluence.temasys.com.sg/display/TWPP/How+to+integrate+the+Temasys+WebRTC+Plugin+into+your+website

Comment: Thanks. I had included this in my project but forgot this step to add it to the sample. However, It gave me a hint.

Comment: Thats Awesome :)